# Can we directly upgrade Oracle 12.1 to 19 c or do we need to upgrade 12.1 to 12.2 first and then 19c

Tags: oracle

Can we directly upgrade Oracle 12.1 to 19 c or do we need to upgrade 12.1 to 12.2 first and then 19c, and when 19c will be available for download

Comment: 12CR2 is 12.2.0.1 18c is 12.2.0.2 and 19c is 12.2.0.3 - but short answer is 'yes' you can upgrade straight from 12cR1 to 19c. You'll want to consult the 19c upgrade guide when it's published. Here's the one for 18 - it should be VERY similar https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/18/upgrd/index.html

Comment: While 18c is 12.2.0.2 (that got renamed), 19c is most definitely NOT 12.2.0.3. It is a major release, coming out in 2019 (hence the version number).

Comment: @AlbertGodfrind 19 is nothing else than 12.2.0.3. Have a look at https://support.oracle.com/epmos/faces/DocContentDisplay?id=742060.1

Comment: @AlbertGodfrind - If thatjeffsmith says 19c is 12.2.0.3, then I'd go to the bank on it.  Do you know who he is?  If not, I'd spend a little time with google finding out . . .

Comment: Check this link [Mike Dietrich](https://mikedietrichde.com/2018/10/18/to-which-release-should-you-upgrade-to-plus-extended-support/)

Comment: @Sam yes especially the new dates here https://mikedietrichde.com/2018/12/14/premier-support-extension-for-oracle-19c-and-more/

Comment: @thatjeffsmith you should submit your comment as an answer

Answer (score 1):

The term used by Oracle is "*direct upgrade*". You have to take into consideration if your database is a multitenant (CDB) database.

From https://mikedietrichde.com/2018/12/14/premier-support-extension-for-oracle-19c-and-more/ :

> *Oracle 12.2.0.1, Oracle 18c and Oracle 19c all together sail under the cover of the “Oracle 12.2 Release Family” and hence have a common support frame*

So direct upgrade should be available with the following versions: `11.2.0.3, 11.2.0.4, 12.1.0.1, 12.1.0.2, 12.2.0.1`

I'm not adding the MOS support hyperlinks since if you are posting the question here I'm guessing you dont have a MOS account.